# AJAX Request to PHP script being cached?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a PHP script that shuffles and array and returns it in a random order based off some parameters. If I directly input the script / parameters into the url, the output of the PHP script is random like it should be. The returned array is shuffled (I use `shuffle($array)` to do this).

Whenever I call it via AJAX, I get the same result no matter what. It will always return the same order. I've tried changing my $.get to $.ajax and setting cache to false, it didn't work, I've sent a parameter along with the $.get request that had a value of $.now() to break the cache.

No matter what I do, when I call the script, it returns the same order, but if I go to it directly in the URL, no problems, random every time.

The request looks something like this:

```
$.get("scripts/findAnime.php", { q: JSON.stringify(params) }, function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

That's without any cache busting, but, like I said, I even tried cache busting methods, and nothing is working.

PHP shuffle looks something like this. There are multiple arrays that get put into $generatedAnimeList, but they all go through a process like this.

If I make the ajax call and just return $least, it will return the same every time, instead of being randomly shuffled.

```
if(!empty($least)) {
    shuffle($least);
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($least); $i++) {
        array_push($generatedAnimeList, $least[$i]['id']);
    }
    unset($least);
}
```

I don't know what to do. I had similar code to this before and it worked perfectly.

### Update

So I put in the script:

```
$temp = array(1,2,3,4,5);
shuffle($temp);
echo json_encode($temp);
```

And the request returns the same "random" order every time. So something with the request has to be incorrect.

### Update

Cleared my browser cache, did nothing. Still receive the same answer. I did discover based off the parameter (q), I will get a different answer. So going based off the above example, where I am simply shuffling an array. If I send q with a value of "ALL", it will always return the same number, and if I send q with the value of "ACTION", it will always return the same number, but different from when q was "ALL".

### Update

I've stripped this thing down to the following. A JS file that makes a get request:

```
$.get("scripts/findAnime.php"+$.now(), function(data, status){
    console.log(data);
}
```

and the php script (findAnime.php) is this:

```
$temp = array(1,2,3,4,5);
shuffle($temp);
echo json_encode($temp);
```

No matter what, always get the same "shuffled" result. In my case, [5,4,1,2,3], every time.

### Update

I can confirm that the JS is making a request to the PHP script and is returning a 200 every time. So it's requesting a new copy, at least supposedly.

Comment: How does it work if you open url to the php script in a separete browser tab (an ordinary get request)?

Comment: Works fine. If I navigate directly to the php script it'll be random. I can refresh all day long and always get a random result.

Comment: It may be the issue with `JSON.stringify`. Did you try to add some  `$.now()` value to your `params`?

Comment: what are the params you're seding?

Comment: Yes. I've tried that multiple different ways. I don't think it is JSON.stringify, or don't think it could be. Because even with my update, where I literally just have an array, shuffle it, and return the shuffle without any regard to the parameter, it doesn't work.

Comment: Params are genres, so it's a JSON.stringify of an array like Action, adventure, comedy, etc. However, even when ignorning the parameters completely, with the simple array shuffle as in my update, I get the same result back.

Comment: Can you try: `$.get("scripts/findAnime.php?" + $.now(), {q: JSON.stringify(params)}, ...` ?

Comment: Tried. Same exact result.

Comment: Which result you get then you try to open same url with direct request (opening it with browser)?

Comment: Try a `CRTL` + `SHIFT` + `F5`, if the result is now correct, its a caching issue.

Comment: Still gives same result. Interestingly enough. I have two different pages that call the same function. On one page, it'll return random no matter what, on the other, returns the same value over and over again. I can't figure out what the difference is between the two..

Comment: *Consider marking the correct answer as such so as to clear this post from the unanswered list.*

Comment: Apologies, it wouldn't let me mark it right away. I have had a busy couple of days. It is marked now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!!!!!**

So... I feel like an idiot now. It was not a caching issue, far from it, actually. On my page, I set the PHP srand function to have a seed, since I have a part of the page that changes based off the day...

Apparently the `srand()` function also affects the `shuffle()` function's randomness.

So, after using `srand(mktime(0,0,0))`, I reset it by calling it again, `srand()`, and TADA! Random numbers!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following headers on the PHP script:

```
header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=1");
header("Expires: ".gmdate('r', time()+1));
```

Also, check  your server for other caching methods like mod_PageSpeed and varnish

Comment: I've already had those headers on the PHP script to begin with, so that isn't the issue. Unfortunately.